# How to match find maximum number of pairs between object type A and object B?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of object type `A` and another list of object type `B`. Each object of type `A` has a list of object type `B` that it can be matched with or be compatible with. (For example, object `A3` could be arbitrarily paired with object `B1`, `B5`, `B7`). Each object A can have a different list of object B that it can be compatible with (some object `A` could be compatible with the same object from `B`). But each object `A` can be paired with only one object from `B`. A object `B` can only be with one object `A`.

What kind of algorithm would help find the maximum number of pairs possible?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're not looking for a brute force algorithm that simply loops through every possible pairing scenario?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, only if there are no other methods. Would this be considered as something that can't be computed in polynomial time?

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to know how best to ask or search for answers to this question without knowing its name, but I believe this is an example of Maximal Matching for a bipartite graph. You an find examples on Wikipedia and Google such as:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)
- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/
- http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Bipartite-Graph-to-Find-the-Maximal-Matching

My understanding of the suggested solution is as follows:

1. For each A, link it to the first valid B.
2. If B is already linked to another A, recursively check if the other A can be linked to a different B, excluding the B that it was linked to through the rest of the recursive search.
3. If it can, then re-assign other A to other B, otherwise pick the next B for this A and repeat from step 2 (recursively).

Without knowing this solution, I implemented my own possibly imperfect solution a year or two ago, described here:

[How to prune duplicate associations to yield a unique most-complete set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279693/how-to-prune-duplicate-associations-to-yield-a-unique-most-complete-set)

One thing I noticed in the process that might help you: if you encounter any A or B that can only link to 1 node on the other side, you may want to automatically pick that path and eliminate all other possibilities for the nodes on both ends (repeat until no more are eliminated). If you know that every node should be linked, this might help optimize your search time.